# Dynamically Changing DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS Without Re-login

Tags: linux, environment-variables, dbus, centos8, gdm

I need to dynamically change `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in a project running on a Linux system. However, this change must occur when I login to the system or open a new session. This should be possible without causing issues with `GDM (Gnome Display Manager).` The methods I've tried so far have failed and caused problems with `GDM` and many other systems to. Below are the steps I tried and the results I got.

My main goal is using  `Dbus` system via `tcp` for provide synchronized properties.
For example, controlling the video that plays in `VLC media player` in both devices and I want to control both of them bidirectional.

First I added a command to change the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to the `.bashrc` file. However, this only caused problems with `GDM` and I cannot login successfully.

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="tcp:host=10.0.5.165,bind=*,port=2334,family=ipv4"
```

Then I wrote a `.sh` script for exporting `Dbus` address after I login and adding the scrip path to .`bashrc`. I successfully login but `Dbus` address did not change. Right after this point, I learned that the dbus address is only read once when relogin is made for security reasons and cannot be changed environmentally.

Also I try creating a `dbus-tcp.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Dbus TCP Service

After=network-online.target


[Service]
ExecStart=dbus-daemon --config-file /usr/share/dbus-1/dbus-tcp.conf
ExecStop=/opt/yaltes/redis/libexec/redis-shutdown
Type=simple

RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With this cutom `dbus-tcp.conf` file in `/usr/share/dbus-1`

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <!-- Our well-known bus type, don't change this -->
  <type>session</type>

  <keep_umask/>

  <listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=2334,family=ipv4</listen>

<listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>

<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>

<allow_anonymous/>

<apparmor mode="disabled"/>

  
  

  <standard_session_servicedirs />

  <policy context="default">
   ...
    <allow own="*"/>
  </policy>

    #<include ignore_missing="yes">/etc/dbus-1/session.conf</include>

  <includedir>session.d</includedir>

  <includedir>/etc/dbus-1/session.d</includedir>

  <!-- This is included last so local configuration can override what's 
       in this standard file -->
  <include ignore_missing="yes">/etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf</include>

  <include if_selinux_enabled="yes" selinux_root_relative="yes">contexts/dbus_contexts</include>


  <!-- the memory limits are 1G instead of say 4G because they can't exceed 32-bit signed int max -->
  ...

</busconfig>
```

When I save it and reboot, the login screen didn't even open.

Lastly I wrote
export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="tcp:host=10.0.5.165,bind=*,port=2334,family=ipv4"`
in to `/etc/environment`  then reboot. After that i successfully change `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` but only for `root`. So when i was root and typed

```
     echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

it gave me the correct address.